# FRM-93652: The runtime process has terminated abnormally

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I faced the error:

> **FRM-93652: The runtime process has terminated abnormally.**
>
> Contact your system administrator.
>
> Details .....
>
> Forms session ID is formsapp.20
>
> *`Form : Oracle Fusion 12c` `DB : Oracle 12c` `Weblogic server : 12c`*

When i am trying to access oracle test form without sso configuration , the form display well.

But once i setup sso configuration (set `ssoMode=webgate` ) , i got this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `SSOMODE=TRUE` or `SSOMODE=WEBGATE` for `Oracle Forms - Version 12.2.1.0.0 and later`, then the following solutions may be applied :

> **Ouick Workaround** : *Changing `SSOMODE` setting in `formsweb.cfg` to `FALSE` that allows the form to run without issue*.

***or***

> ***Solution by Console*** :
>
> - Log in to the OAM Administration Console.
> - Select `Authentication Schemes` and navigate to `PasswordPolicyValidationscheme` (or `LDAPScheme`).
> - Set the `ssoCookie` parameter value to `disablehttponly`.
> - Click Apply

Answer (score 0):

I applied the solution 2 as you can see in this picture. By this way users can not

access forms application with the port 9001 since i set SSOMODE setting in

formsweb.cfg to WEBGATE

So the solution 2 seems to be the best one.

Thank you guy

[image]